# Mystery plant growing in yard? TX

Tags: identification, planting

This is long and semi-waxy, but soft. I was just outside re-potting some other plants and was thinking about pulling some other flowers that had spread and came across this. It's like.. hair. It doesn't hold itself up and really long. It makes like a 'U' shape at the base but the ends are flat.

[image: mystery plant. long]

[image: flat on one end, 'u' shape at the base.]

Update: Sap is just liquid-y. Not sticky, not a lot comes out unless you squeeze it. The smell is...a mix of fresh cut grass and the smell of when you are scraping out a pumpkin, but it's **really** subtle. You have to have it close to your nose and breath really deep to smell it. I also took another picture of how long it is compared to my foot. I wear a size 8 and a half in womens and it takes 3 of my feet to come close to the length.

[image: sap]

[image: length]

EDIT! 
So it's is now Oct! And the flowers ha e bloomed but I'm still not sure that they are. They are red and bloom in a cluster. I have a picture of them with my Purple Hearts. I can't upload from my phone right now though.

Comment: Betcha money it grows from a bulb. Has it flowered? Is there a scent to the leaves when crushed? What is the sap like?

Comment: Hasn't flowered that I know of. I just got back to TX about a week ago and I don't remember it before I left. I've been gone about 7 months so it could be anything that a bird may have dropped from the neighborhood. Give me a moment and I'll check and get more pictures.

Comment: @J.Musser I updated my post

Comment: Agree with J Musser, everything about the plants growth habit, leaf shape, and the timing screams of a spring (or in your climate, winter) bulb plant. Given its size I would expect it to flower before March, so if nobody recognizes it before then post pictures of the blooms.

Comment: I also agree, it kinda has a day lily quality to it.

Comment: @GardenerJ I will be keeping an eye on it for sure and will post pics if it blooms! All I know now is in the post and I'm excited to figure this out!

Comment: It still hasn't flowered. Just long leaves.

Comment: @GardenerJ So it's been a while and the plant is dying off for summer. No blooming. The long leave did seem to get red marks on it though.

Comment: @GardenerJ it bloomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, This finally bloomed and I had just started using GardenTags. They helped me identify it as Oxblood Lily/Schoolhouse Lily!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Daffodil (Narcissus) - Probably one that's come up blind/not flowered due to lack of nutrients.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(plant)

OR since October Update

Hesperantha coccinea 'Major'

https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=1806

Comment: I thought so too, but they have a gooey sap, unlike what the OP has experienced.... It would make sense, though, sometimes daffodils don't flower consistently in warm climates.

Comment: But the Leaves are all droopy? I'm not seeing other Daffodil with super long leaves like this :/

Comment: @J. Musser It bloomed!

Comment: What was it? Daffodil?

Comment: Photo of the bloom? If you don't have one, just do a general search for flowering daffodils or flowering blooms and try to see if you can find us the flower.